# Flash CS6 performance issue while editing nested symbols

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

Sorry, this isn't an AS3 issue but I hope some others out there who use CS6 regularly can chime in:

I've noticed considerable performance degradation in Flash CS6 when editing nested symbols using "Edit in Place" (double-clicking a symbol), and to a lesser extent using "Edit". By nested I'm referring to a symbol within a symbol, within a symbol, etc. Are there known limitations to the depth of nested symbols that I should try to optimize to? The canvas refresh lag is noticeable around 5 symbols deep, and can become atrocious beyond that. I'm using CS6 to build my art assets and exporting spritesheets directly from the library - no video, imported images, or text anywhere in the FLA, so performance at publication is not a concern.

Am I using too many nested graphic symbols for Flash to handle? I assumed by now that Flash performance would only be getting better with each release, not worse. Flash is no where near maxing out my RAM (uses ~450Mb of 8Gb), CPU (Core i7 2600), or GPU (AMD HD-6900) - so what gives? Can't even use a Wacom with these lag issues deep within nested symbols.

Thanks in advance for any insight - this has brought my productivity at times to a standstill.